# Solution of maze

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have coded a random maze and it's path generator that shows output on turtle window. The problem is that this solves the maze but by passing through the walls of the maze can somebody help me tell & how can I restrict my code to obey the right path and avoid touching the walls of the maze

This is the code of maze and path is generated on the python turtle window

```
import turtle
import random

cell_size = 10


def generate_maze(width, height):
    maze = [['-'] * (2 * width + 1) for _ in range(2 * height + 1)]

    def carve(x, y):
        directions = [(2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2), (0, -2)]
        random.shuffle(directions)

        for dx, dy in directions:
            nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy

            if 0 < nx < 2 * width and 0 < ny < 2 * height and maze[ny][nx] == '-':
                maze[ny][nx] = ' '
                maze[y + dy // 2][x + dx // 2] = ' '
                carve(nx, ny)

    start_x, start_y = 1, 2 * height - 1
    end_x, end_y = width * 2 - 1, 1

    maze[start_y][start_x] = ' '
    maze[end_y][end_x] = ' '

    carve(start_x, start_y)

    return maze


def draw_maze_with_turtle(maze):
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.bgcolor('black')
    turtle.color('white')

    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == '-':
                turtle.penup()
                turtle.goto(x * cell_size - width * cell_size, height * cell_size - y * cell_size)
                turtle.pendown()
                turtle.forward(cell_size)
                turtle.right(90)
                turtle.forward(cell_size)
                turtle.right(90)
                turtle.forward(cell_size)
                turtle.right(90)
                turtle.forward(cell_size)
                turtle.right(90)


def solve_maze(maze, start, end):
    stack = [start]
    visited = set()

    while stack:
        x, y = stack[-1]

        if (x, y) == end:
            break

        found = False
        for dx, dy in [(0, 2), (0, -2), (2, 0), (-2, 0)]:
            nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy

            if 0 <= nx < 2 * width and 0 <= ny < 2 * height and maze[ny][nx] == ' ' and (nx, ny) not in visited:
                visited.add((nx, ny))
                stack.append((nx, ny))
                found = True
                break

        if not found:
            stack.pop()

    return stack


def draw_path_with_turtle(path):
    turtle.pencolor('green')
    turtle.pensize(3)

    for x, y in path:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x * cell_size - width * cell_size + cell_size / 2, height * cell_size - y * cell_size + cell_size / 2)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.dot(cell_size - 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    width = 60
    height = 5

    maze = generate_maze(width, height)

    start_x, start_y = 1, 2 * height - 1
    maze[start_y][start_x] = ' '

    draw_maze_with_turtle(maze)

    start = (start_x, start_y)
    end = (width * 2 - 1, 1)

    path = solve_maze(maze, start, end)
    draw_path_with_turtle(path)

    turtle.delay(0)
    turtle.done()
```

A solution for the path touching the walls

Comment: There doesn't seem to be code that attempts to solve the maze? Then what is holding you back?

Comment: I wrote the code but that didn't work so I removed so others don't get confused

Comment: Then your question will not get much attention. Questions should show the effort, and the problem that occurred during that attempt, with code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok sir will try that

Comment: Sir I did exactly what you told me to do let's see it works or not......

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, with the first two issues being the real blockers:

- In `solve_maze`, you need to make steps by 1, not by 2, as otherwise you "jump" over walls. So change:

  ```
  for dx, dy in [(0, 2), (0, -2), (2, 0), (-2, 0)]:
  ```

  to:

  ```
  for dx, dy in [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]:
  ```
- In `generate_maze` you will never allow a path to the end cell, because you start by clearing that cell, and so it will remain isolated for ever. You need to remove this statement: `maze[end_y][end_x] = ' '`
- In `solve_maze` you need to mark the start cell as visited immediately, so at the top of the function, define it with `visited = set(stack)`
- In `draw_path_with_turtle`, the y-coordinate to plot needs `- cell_size / 2` instead of `+ cell_size / 2`.

With those fixes it will work.

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful!
If you wish to do so, you can also [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), but it is optional.

Comment: I want to change the cell to simple lines but that didn't worked. So can you please tell me how can I change these cells to simple straight lines.

Comment: If you have a new question, then please post it as a new question, and make sure to add your attempt at it.